# Adding points every second independent from the rest of the program

Tags: python, input, timer, pygame

```
bal=0

while True:
  input="Click! > "
  bal=bal+1
```

In this case, whenever the input is done (enter is pressed), balance goes up by 1.
When you reach 1000 bal, you will be able to buy an autoclicker that adds 1 bal every second.
But while the autoclicker is working, the program shouldn't stop, so, you should be able to continue to click while also taking the coins from the autoclicker.

It should also work when you are not clicking (AFK) or clicking slower than 1 cps.

I feel like that needs a timer that works in the background, adding 1 bal every second, but it shouldn't stop the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom event to do this. See the following:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.constants import *
#initialise pygame
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((100,100))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
font=pygame.font.SysFont("Verdana",10)
#variables
bal=0
autoclickers=0
running=True
#create custom event. Note that you have to use USEREVENT+1 for the following event, +2 for the next...
secondpassed=USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(secondpassed,1000)
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            running=False
        elif event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_RETURN:
            #enter pressed
            bal+=1
        elif event.type==secondpassed:
            #event passed, add autoclickers
            bal+=autoclickers
        elif event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and bal>5:
            #autoclicker bought
            autoclickers+=1
            bal-=5
    #render amount of balls
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    balls=font.render("balls: "+str(bal),False,(0,0,0))
    screen.blit(balls,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Note that this does not schedule a timer upon an autoclicker is bought, so the time between the buying and the first ball gain will be less then 1 second. After that, it will be 1 second.